# Setup for producing multiple documents based on the same source file

Tags: document-classes, output, document-configuration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Guide to managing multiple resume with one LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/guide-to-managing-multiple-resume-with-one-latex)

I would like to make a combined résumé & CV document class that can be used to generate two documents with some content shared and some content unique to one of the documents. Is there a way to do this with a single LaTeX file? If not, what do you recommend doing instead?

Comment: You can define your own documentclass that sets the style accourding to some class options and/or key-value pairs. The `pgfkeys` package is excellent for parsing key-value pairs and the `pgfopts` package lets you use `pgfkeys` at the document class level. As to the style, thst's up to yourself. For example, you could load class `X` if option `A` is passed, load class `Y` if option `B` is passed, and so on.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Is there a way I could actually produce two PDF files?

Comment: In general, it's always simpler to have separate (main) input files for each output PDF that you need, but this doesn't mean duplicating a lot of text. Take a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1647/guide-to-managing-multiple-resume-with-one-latex), and also [this answer.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77791/344)

Comment: Can you please expand on the common parts with example headings, i.e., short-bio (you may have it on both a resume and a CV).

Comment: You can easily produce two pdf files, then combine them using `pdfpages` package

Comment: @jtbandes I can't see how you can do this from within LaTeX because it only allows one `documentclass` per document. However, you can generate two pdfs from the shell level. `echo '\ifcsname ifarticle\endcsname\else\expandafter\let\csname ifarticle\expandafter\endcsname\csname iffalse\endcsname\fi\ifarticle\documentclass{article}\else\documentclass{book}\fi\title{Example}\author{Somebody}\begin{document}\maketitle\end{document}' > ex.tex; pdflatex "\let\ifarticle\iffalse\input{ex}"; mv ex.pdf book.pdf; pdflatex "\let\ifarticle\iftrue\input{ex}"; mv ex.pdf article.pdf`

Answer (score 5):

## The best idea (aka poor man's solution)

will be to have two main files (say `first.tex` and `second.tex`) which will have content unique to them. The shared content may be in a third file (say `shared.tex`) which can be `\input`ed inside `first.tex` and `second.tex`. Hence you will have totally three files.

If you want all the three files inside a single file and want to compile (click the `pdflatex` button `,-)`) only once, you may use the `filecontents` and `\write` facility:

(name this file as `first.tex`)

```
\documentclass{article} %% The output of this file is the first document.
\usepackage{filecontents}%
%%
%% The shared content
\begin{filecontents*}{shared.tex}
This content is shared by both the files -- \verb|first.tex| and \verb|second.tex|
\end{filecontents*}
%%
%% This is the second document
\begin{filecontents*}{second.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is the unique content for the second file. Next comes the shared content.
\section{shared content}
\input{shared}

Again some unique content for second file.
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%%
%create the second.pdf.
\immediate\write18{pdflatex second}

\begin{document}
 This will appear only in the first file. I am going crazy!
 \section{shared content}
\input{shared}

Again this is only for first file.

\end{document}
```

You will get two pdf files - `first.pdf` and `second.pdf`. The contents of `first.pdf` are

[image]

and the `second.pdf` reads:

[image]

Comment: This works but it is not easy to share many different bits of generated text between the two output files.